# Converting WP Page to use full explicit paths?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm integrating a 3rd party product db/search feature into an existing/live Wordpress website using the vendor's Remote HTML Framing Code template.

They are asking me to "convert all paths to full"

Apparently, the Remote HTML Framing Code template needs all URLs on the integration page template to use full explicit paths.

The page template in question is here: http://www.stonegategardens.com/stonegate-gardens-plant-finder-tool/

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to make this work?

Thanks Mike

Comment: WP inherently prefers to use full paths for everything. Where precisely do you have relative paths and why?

Comment: The integration is not working and the 3rd party vendor has told me this was the reason. I don't know for sure that I do ...